# Xamarin webview WebPage Cant download files mSecurityInputMethodService is null

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin, I'm using this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows) as a base for my on application. I just noticed when I click in a link to download files, it doesnt do anything, but i can see in the consoloe the next error

**mSecurityInputMethodService is null**

I saw this as an approach, but it didnt do anything at all

```
    private void WebView_OnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url.ToLower().Contains("forcesave=true") || e.Url.ToLower().Contains("pdf"))
        {
            var uri = new Uri(e.Url);
            Device.OpenUri(uri);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Can you please give me some advice?

Comment: Do you want to download files from a webview?

Comment: Yes, the user will be browsing through my website with the WebView, there are some urls with files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom renderer for webview.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), 
     typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace TwoCollen.Droid
{
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.WebView, global::Android.Webkit.WebView>
{
    public CustomWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (this.Control == null)
        {
            var webView = new global::Android.Webkit.WebView(this.Context);
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.Settings;
            webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled=true;
            webView.SetDownloadListener(new CustomDownloadListener());
            this.SetNativeControl(webView);
            var source = e.NewElement.Source as UrlWebViewSource;
            if (source != null)
            {
                webView.LoadUrl(source.Url);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CustomDownloadListener : Java.Lang.Object, IDownloadListener
{
    public void OnDownloadStart(string url, string userAgent, string contentDisposition, string mimetype, long contentLength)
    {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
        request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
        request.SetDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Forms.Context, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, "mydeddp.pdf");
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.App.Application.DownloadService);
        dm.Enqueue(request);
    }
}
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: @David Alejandro García García did you try above method?

Comment: yes and is working, but now when i click go back button it wont work
i created this other question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107967/customwebviewrenderer-downloadmanager-issue-with-copybackforwardlist